# Adding and Subtracting Timecode in Excel

Tags: excel, time, addition, subtraction

I need to add and subract timecode in excel. My format for timecode is hh:mm:ss;ff or hours:minutes:seconds;frames.

So an example of subtraction would be 01:01:07;27 - 00:00:06;00 = 01:01:01;27

I need to know how to enter the subtraction formula in Excel.

Comment: Can you share some formulas you have tried?

Comment: How many frames per second?

Comment: I have not tried any formulas because I do not know what to try. 29.97 FPS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this formula:

```
=TEXT(INT(((LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1)+(MID(A1,FIND(";",A1)+1,3)/(29.97*24*60*60)))-(LEFT(B1,FIND(";",B1)-1)+(MID(B1,FIND(";",B1)+1,3)/(29.97*24*60*60))))*24*60*60)/(24*60*60),"hh:mm:ss") & ";" & TEXT(MOD(((LEFT(A1,FIND(";",A1)-1)+(MID(A1,FIND(";",A1)+1,3)/(29.97*24*60*60)))-(LEFT(B1,FIND(";",B1)-1)+(MID(B1,FIND(";",B1)+1,3)/(29.97*24*60*60))))*24*60*60,1)*29.97,"00.00")
```

[image]